# Calculation of natural cubic splines in R

Tags: r, splines

I am new to the use of cubic splines for regression purposes and wanted to find out

1) What is a good source (besides ESL which I read but am still uncertain) to learn about splines for regression? 
2) How would you calculate the basis of a given natural cubic spline solution on new data? Specifically if one were to do the following:

```
data(iris)
colnames(iris)
Sepal.Length.ns<-ns(iris$Sepal.Length,df=5)
Sepal.Length.ns
```

How would you take the information in Sepal.Length.ns (knots, boundaries) and compute the values for a new observation? The reason is to code this process outside of R, once fit in R initially (i.e. to put a regression model using cubic splines into a production system).

For example I can do this in R, but want to understand the calculation:

```
#three new observations to predict
newVector<-c(4.45,3.35,2.2)
pred.new<-predict(Sepal.Length.ns,newVector)
```

Thanks!

Comment: try `?splinefun`

Comment: I had a similar question, so I made a [google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E8ozpvn5O1euQtNcaiMLqa-QP4Q_PBpoAX7TgeKYCkU/edit?usp=sharing) which walks through the calculation for bs() in R. Hopefully its helpful! Definitely learned a lot[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80iYj.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80iYj.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wikipedia has a [nice explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation) of spline interpolation

I posted the code to create cubic [Bezier splines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_spline) on [Rosettacode](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bitmap/B%C3%A9zier_curves/Cubic#R) a while ago.

Also, you can have a look at [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881143/cubic-spline-extrapolation) on SO about spline extrapolation.

Comment: Do these show how to calculate the new variables from new data (i.e what predict() is doing)?

Comment: @B_Miner: yes, the SO link does.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Sorry Nico, I went to click on the other button! It wont let me change it. I will try to edit your answer ever so slightly and then vote it up. I am still trying to figure out how exactly to use compute the variables, seems there must be a simple formula that I am just not seeing in the SO post.

Comment: @B_Miner: don't worry, no problem. PS: depending on the type/amount of data you have, you may want to have a look at LOESS regression.

Answer (score 1):

I learnt about the use of splines in regression from the book "Regression Modeling Strategies" by Frank Harrell. Harrell's R package rms allows you to easily fit regression models in which some predictor variables are represented as splines.